# How often is a thread executed? My Observer pattern gone wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading

The following is a simplified version of my current code. I am pretty sure I am not doing any thing wrong syntax-wise, and I can't locate my conceptual mistake.

This is sort of an observer pattern I tried to implement. I could not afford to inherit from Java.utils.observable as my class is already complicated and inherits from another class.
There are two parts here:

There's a Notifier class implementing Runnable :

```
public class Notifier implements Runnable{

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            MyDataType data = getData();
            if(data.isChanged()==true)
            {
                refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then there is my main class which needs to respond to changes to MyDataType data.

```
public class abc {

    private MyDataType data;

    public void abc(){
               Notifier notifier = new Notifier();
               Thread thread = new Thread(notifier);
               thread.start();
          }     


    public MyDataType getData(){
              return this.data;
    }


    public void refresh(){
         MyDatatype data = getData();
     //Do something with data
    }
}
```

**The problem** : What's happening is that the notifier is calling refresh() when 'data' changes. However inside refresh(), when I do getData(), I am getting the old version of 'data'!
I should mention that there are other parts of the code which are calling the refresh() function too.

- What am I overlooking?
- Any other better solutions to this problem?
- How should I approach designing Subject-Observer systems if I can't apply the default Java  implementation out of the box?

Comment: Without seeing your actual threading code, i.e. how many threads are executed and what contains which part of the code snippets above it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: I feared as much. :(. Will think about this and add edits to my question later on.

Comment: Also, I you really doing that with a busy loop constantly checking id data has changed? This is bad! It will bring your CPU to its knees. You should post a message to a blocking queue when data changes, and have your other thread get messages from the blocking queue.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! @GETah below indicated the code to do that too in one of the answers. I'll implement this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `data` variable might be cached, so you will always need to get the latest value by making it `volatile`.

Second, what you are doing here is a [producer / consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern. This pattern is usually best implemented with messages. When you receive new data, you could create an immutable object and  post it to the consumer thread (via a thread safe queue like a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)) instead of having a shared variable.

Something along these lines:

```
public class Notifier extends Thread{
   private BlockingQueue<E> consumerQueue = null;
   public setConsumerQueue(BlockingQueue<E> val){
      consumerQueue = val;
   }
   // main method where data is received from socket...
   public void run(){
      while(!interrupted()){
           data = ... // got new data here
           if(!data.isChanged()) continue;
           // Post new data only when it has changed
           if(consumerQueue!=null) consumerQueue.offer(data);
      }
   }
}

public class Consumer extends Thread{
   private BlockingQueue<E> consumerQueue = new BlockingQueue<E>();
   public Consumer (Producer val){
      val.setConsumerQueue(consumerQueue);
   }
   public void run(){
      while(!interrupted()){
           data = consumerQueue.take();// block until there is data from producer
           if(data !=null) processData(data);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I learnt about the producer-consumer pattern and the blocking queue technique for the first time here!

Answer (score 4):

> when I do getData(), I am getting the old version of 'data'!

Your `data` field is shared among more than one thread so it must be marked with the `volatile` keyword.

```
private volatile MyDataType data;
```

This causes a "memory barrier" around the read and the the write that keeps the value visible to all threads.  Even though the notifier thread is calling `getData()`, the value for `data` is being retrieved out if its memory cache.  Without the memory barrier, the `data` value will be updated randomly or never.

As @JB mentioned in the comments, the `volatile` protects you against a re-assignment of the `data` field.  If you update one of the fields within the *current* `data` value, the memory barrier will not be crossed that the notifier's memory will not be updated.

Looking back at your code, it looks like this is the case:

```
if(data.isChanged()==true)
{
    refresh();
}
```

If `data` is not being assigned to a new object then making `data` to be `volatile` won't help you.  You will have to:

- Set some sort of `volatile boolean dirty;` field whenever `data` has been updated.
- Update or read `data` within a `synchronize` block each and every time.

Comment: Note that this will only work if a thread assigns a new value to the data field. If something is changed inside the MyDataType object, it will have no effect.

Comment: @Gray and @JB Nizet : Yes, the value of `data` is not being modified by the Notifier thread at all. It is just watched.
`data` will be changed by something else. 

I tried adding `volatile` still, and it does't seem to be working.

Comment: I've updated my answer @pnpranavrao.  You'll see to have a `volatile boolean dirty;` field inside of `data` that you can test in the notifier.  You could also `synchronize` it every time you change it or read it.

Comment: Thanks @Gray! `volatile` and `synchronize` are something new that'll go into my code now.